# sql query in drop down option

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to a display options in dropdown by database.Name of table is location and loc is a column in table of varchar datatype

```
<select style="width: 200px;" name="location" id="myselect" onchange="window.location='enable1.php?id='+this.value+'&pos='+this.selectedIndex;">
  <option value="All">All</option>
  <?php

  $sql="select * from location";
  var_dump($sql);
  $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  echo "1";
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
  {
      echo "<option value='$row[loc]'>'$row[loc]'</option>";
  }
    ?>

</select>
```

But when I load the page I Dont get any output in dropdown. Only 1 option and that is "ALL". Var_dump() also outputs nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around array keys:

```
echo "<option value='$row[loc]'>$row[loc]</option>";// line 123
```

Comment: Okay that helped but now I dont get any result in dropdown

Comment: If you view the source does it contain `<option>` tags?

Comment: view source shows this <select style="width: 200px;" name="location" id="myselect" onchange="window.location='enable1.php?id='+this.value+'&pos='+this.selectedIndex;">
  <option value="All">All</option>
  string(22) "select * from location"
1<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Dashboard\enable1.php</b> on line <b>119</b><br />
 
</select>

Comment: Get rid of var_dump and echo. Switch to the function mysqli_fetch_assoc from mysql_fetch_array